# .Net MVC Ajax and Scriptmanager conflict

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

We have a simple ajax link (Ajax.ActionLink(...)) that has been working fine. Recently, another developer added some ajax-ey code to the same page that uses an asp scriptmanager ... now suddenly the first ajax link no longer works. More specifically we get the error : "sys.mvc.asynchyperlink' is null or not an object". Below is a sample :

```
<a id="linkID"
   href="someURL" 
   onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncHyperlink.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace });">
<img src="linkImage.jpg" />                    
</a>

....

<asp:ScriptManager ID="_someID" EnablePartialRendering="true" ScriptMode="Release" runat="server">
...
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

What is the relationship between these two? Can they coexist?

**EDIT :** 
so, it turns out we are using the scriptmanager to register a ServiceReference to hook into a web service we've set up. The scriptmanager makes the service available from our javascript functions. Is it possible to get the ServiceReference registered/added without using the scriptmanager? This is perhaps a completely different question...

Answer (score 0):

The ScriptManager control is not built to coexist with ASP.NET MVC. Just remove it and replace it with the following:

```
<script src="MicrosoftAjax.js"><script>
```

Note that the path will vary based on where MicrosoftAjax.js is in your project, but it should be in the Static/js folder in any new ASP.NET MVC project.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the MicrosoftAjax.js has already been added to the file. We were using the scriptmanager to register a servicereference as explained above. we will have to figure out another way to do this.

Comment: AFAIK that's not possible. The ScriptManager is required to generate the service proxy, but it will take over the `sys` object and break `sys.mvc`.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, we ended up getting around using the Scriptmanager for the service reference by using a web service proxy, as outlined in this tutorial by Stephen Walther http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/03/14/using-asp-net-ajax-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx